# Account name privacy?

Tags: accounts, account-name

Are accounts linked?  My understanding is you need an account to create a new account.

So suppose you have main account `ABC` and then you create a new account `SupportPoliticalCandidate`:

1. Will it be public information that `ABC` created `SupportPoliticalCandidate`?
2. If you create another account, `YourName`, will it be public information that `YourName` and `SupportPoliticalCandidate` are related?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Will it be public information that ABC created
>      SupportPoliticalCandidate?

yes, every transaction has an id named tranaction id, by query the id, everyone can know what happened.

> 2. If you create another account, YourName, will it be public information that YourName and SupportPoliticalCandidate are related?

yes and no. You can use `cleos get servants ABC` get created accounts by `ABC`, but each of them are not related.
for example:

```
$cleos get servants abc
{
  "controlled_accounts": [
       "SupportPoliticalCandidate",
       "YourName"
   ]
}
```

A bit more: account should be *<= 12 characters of 1-5, a-z* for now, uppercase letter are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

One way for anonymity would be to use an independant account creation service like the one I created: https://eos-account-creator.com/

The accounts by eos account creator are all created by the parent account "accountcreat" and there would be no link to your policitcal candidate :)

Comment: fyi the usual practice on stackexchange seems to be to disclose whether you have some affiliation with a tool you are mentioning